# Add host on Cloudstack

Tags: ubuntu, cloud

i have a question about Cloudstack configuration , my problem is in add host section , 
what is the host specification for it ? Do i have to install Xenserver on that host ?
Thx before

Answer (score 2):

With Apache CloudStack admin questions, you are better to post on the user mailing list.  The mailing list is read and responded to regularly by consultants, users, and developers.

Subscribe by sending an email to cloudstack-users-subscribe@incubator.apache.org

Next, send an email explaining the problem to cloudstack-users@incubator.apache.org

In your case, you need to install XenServer on the host before adding it to the CloudStack server.  Check the docs to see what version of XenServer to use.  You can also google the Apache CloudStack users group archive to see if a similar problem was encountered.  The archive is at http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-cloudstack-users/

Comment: Or if you're in a rush:  a host is the physical server that you'll be running VMs on.  A hypervisor needs to first be installed on the host.  It can run XenServer, KVM, OVM or VMWare hypervisor software, and details for each are in the install guide.

Answer (score 2):

In `CloudStack` host is basic unit of compute which is as bundle called as cluster.
Before Adding host you have create cluster and clusters are `hypervisor` specific,if you are creating `vmware` cluster then while adding cluster you have to give the details of `vcenter` server with `datacenter` and cluster name ,for the first time all host in that particular cluster will get added automatically and later if you add any new host to cluster you can add through `cloudstack` add host `gui` or `cloudmonkey` `cli` .If the cluster is of `xen` server then you will add all hosts which would be individual `xen` servers  manually.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to install Ubuntu, Xen/KVM and configure the host before adding using the "add host section"

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the Installation Document to make it work, it's very clear.No matter you want to use KVM or Xen as a hypervisor. This is the link http://docs.cloudstack.apache.org/projects/cloudstack-installation/en/latest/qig.html#kvm-setup-and-installation

Comment: This is a KVM example.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. 
Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which virtualization you are using ?

Which virtualization you chose during first stage on zone addition ?

If you chose KVM then make sure host/Server is installed with KVM and cloudstack-agent.
If you are using Xen, then make sure xenserver is installed on the server/host.